# Using Both Elasticsearch and Sphinx

Tags: search, elasticsearch, sphinx

I have currently sphinx integrated in my website. 
Now i thought of integrating Elastic Search for some other Search features which i haven't yet built with sphinx.

I thought to migrate to Elastic Search. But I do not want to change my previous integration from sphinx to elastic search (right now).

Is there any major issue if i use both search engines ?

Answer (score 0):

Use more resources. Like more RAM, more diskspace, and increased CPU. Also more contention on database if both index at the same time. Need powerful enough server

And more maintenance as would need to maintain two packages, updates etc likely to be on different schedules